# how do i change the color of a span tag on mouse over, but only the span tag that the mouse is over?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

here is what i have, i figured it would only change red, the one span that the mouse is over, but once you put the mouse over, they all change red

```
<p><span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="大地(Daichi) ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land">(大地)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="が(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">(が)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="揺れ(Yure) vibration/flickering/jolting/tremor">(揺れ)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="始め(Hajime) beginning/start/outset/opening/  first / origin/  such as .../not to mention ...">(始め)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="、(、) Japanese comma">(、)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="警報(Keihou) alarm/warning">(警報)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="が(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">(が)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="鳴り(Nari) ringing/sound">(鳴り&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>)(<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="響い(Hibii) no dictionary result, likely a conjigated verb">響い</span>)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="た(ta) indicate past completed or action/ indicates light imperative">(た</span>)</p>
```

how do i make each span change on its own mouseover event?

Comment: if you can use jQuery, this is trivial

Comment: You shouldn't use javascript for this; you should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, the problem is that you have a `span` inside other `span` and so on.

You should add one `span` and then other, so when you pass the mouse over the first `span` it looks like all gets red because they are inside.

```
<p>
    <span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="大地(Daichi) ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land">(大地)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="大地(Daichi) ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land">(大地)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sr56/)

Comment: Should add `onmouseout` too, to revert to previous state

Answer (score 6):

It is simpler and move efficient to use the CSS :hover pseudoclass for this purpose. I have prepared [an example in JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Bd39K)

```
<style>
span:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
</style>
<span>I think</span>
<span>that</span>
<span>I shall</span>
<span>never</span>
<span>see</span>
<br>
<span>a poem as lovely</span>
<span>as</span>
<span>a tree</span>​
```

Comment: Yes, hover is definitely the best way to do it. JavaScript is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with CSS with the :hover attribute although if you really want to use javascript simple attach an event the the individual element. here is a very simple example.

simply make your span elements use something like 
`var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');`

to select them and loop through them applying the event.

here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tate/ztgRL/9/

Answer (score 0):

See this code... (assemble with your code)

```
<p>
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='green'" title="??(Daichi) ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land">
(??)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="?(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">
(?)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="??(Yure) vibration/flickering/jolting/tremor">
(??)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="??(Hajime) beginning/start/outset/opening/  first / origin/  such as .../not to mention ...">
(??)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="?(?) Japanese comma">
(?)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="??(Keihou) alarm/warning">
(??)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="?(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">
(?)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span onmouseover="this.style.background='red'" title="??(Nari) ringing/sound">
(??)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</p>
```